# How does ParameterizedTypeReference work with type erasure

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have this code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<A>> type1 = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<A>>() {};
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<B>> type2 = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<B>>() {};
    Type t1 = getType(type1);
    Type t2 = getType(type2);

    // prints false. How does it work here as there is no type in run time!
    System.out.println(t1.equals(t2)); 
}


public static <T> Type getType(ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> typeReference) {
    Type type = typeReference.getType();
    System.out.println(type.getTypeName());
    return type;
}
```

Comment: Erasure does not remove type information from class definitions.  As for equality, it appears [the contract of ParameterizedType](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) does not guarantee that any two types will be equal.

Comment: It would be good to see what kind of output you have running this code.